# c++ lambda expression function using reference causes segmentation fault

Tags: lambda, pass-by-reference

I get a problem when dealing with c++ lambda expression.
Here is my code:

```
using FUNC = std::function<int(int, int)>;

FUNC unit( const FUNC& lf, const FUNC& rt ) {
    return [&]( int first, int second ) -> int {
        return lf( first, second ) + rt( first, second );
    };
}

int input( int first, int second ) {
    return first;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    FUNC x2 = unit( input, input );
    x2( 10, 1 );
    FUNC x3 = unit( x2, x2 );
    auto result = x3( 10, 1 );

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When running, x2(10,1) is fine, but x3(10,1) causes segmentation fault.
If I change lambda expression in "unit" from [&] to [=], everything is fine.

Debug STL library is too much for me, can someone explain why ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function to parameter `const FUNC&`, a temporary `FUNC` is formed to bind to the const reference. Then the lambda captures that temporary by reference; so the `x2` contains references to these temporary `FUNCs` which were destroyed at the end of the previous line.

So your code is using dangling references.

Capturing by value works because there are no dangling references. In fact it would be even better to use `FUNC` in the first place instead of `const FUNC&` as the parameter to `unit`.

Comment: I am still confused why x2(10, 1) works if x2 contains dangling references ?

Comment: @MingyuLu undefined behaviour means anything can happen

Comment: Bravo. I add some extra lines before x2(10, 1) then it fails. That's exactly the problem. Thanks a lot. @M.M